# How to Store the user extra info in user meta table

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I have two table `user` and `usermeta` table.
in user table am storing the

```
name, email, password.
```

Now I want to store the extra information of user in the `usermeta` table like its

```
user id, first name and last name.
```

I am not understanding how to do. I am just a new to laravel.

Comment: Why you need ``usermeta`` table to store firstname and lastname. You can store the same info in your user table? any special reason...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, read about eloquent relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships

In Models/User.php define relation to usermeta table:

```
/**
 * Get the meta record associated with the user.
 */
public function meta()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Usermeta', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Now you can:

```
// load extra data
$user = User::find(1);
dd($user->meta);

// also with lazy eager loading
$users = User::limit(10)->get();
$users->load('meta');
dd($users);

// save extra data
$user->meta->first_name = 'John';
$user->meta->save();

// or save through meta() relationship instance
$user = User::find(1);
$meta = new Usermeta;
$meta->first_name = 'John';
$user->meta()->save($meta);
```

And so on